# How to check if first day of week is Monday or Sunday in DELPHI ANDROID?

Tags: android, date, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is there a simple way to check if first day of week is Monday or Sunday in DELPHI on ANDROID device?

Comment: I presume you are using RAD studio, and have it setup properly? If you are and have not see setup tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OmWPVOfPnI, are you also familiar with Android libraries and Java 6? If not I suggest learning them to better your Android development. I use Java on Android and for time its recommended to use `Calendar` class in `java.util` by default the Calendar class gets the current time in milliseconds and the you want to use `get` method in class passing in `DAY_OF_WEEK` constant to get day of week see https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this code:

```
var
  Calendar: JCalendar;
  UsedFirstDayOfWeek: integer;
begin
  //For default locale use code
  Calendar := TJCalendar.JavaClass.getInstance(TJLocale.JavaClass.getDefault);

  //For US locale (etc UK, ...) use code
  Calendar := TJCalendar.JavaClass.getInstance(TJLocale.JavaClass.US);

  UsedFirstDayOfWeek:= Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek;

  //Constants used in result
  SUNDAY    Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
  MONDAY    Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)
  TUESDAY   Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)
  WEDNESDAY Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)
  THURSDAY  Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)
  FRIDAY    Constant Value: 6 (0x00000006)
  SATURDAY  Constant Value: 7 (0x00000007)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 GregorianCalendar tepCal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                Date todayDate = new Date();
                tepCal.setTime(todayDate);
                tepCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
                tepCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);// November
                tepCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
                dayOfweek = tepCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1; //It returns 4 (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK  returns 1 for sunday)
```